# CSS Property Condition According to Browser

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a CSS property:

```
top:20px;
```

It is Ok with Internet Explorer but not with FireFox. It should be that for Firefox:

```
top:0px;
```

How can I add that conditionally situation at CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following conditional statement into your CSS

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .className {
        top:0px;
    }
}
```

Any CSS in-between `@-moz-document url-prefix()` will only be applied to Firefox.

But maybe a better choice would be to apply a conditional to IE instead. You could leave `top:0px;` in your current CSS and add the following conditional for IE in the `head` of your document.

```
<!--[if IE]>
   <style>
      .className {
         top:20px;
      }
   </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Note: Conditional comments are not supported in IE10+

Comment: Conditional comments are not supported in IE10+ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Found this piece of script [here](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/167820) that could be of great use to you.

```
   // This function returns Internet Explorer's major version number,
   // or 0 for others. It works by finding the "MSIE " string and
   // extracting the version number following the space, up to the decimal
   // point, ignoring the minor version number
   <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaSCRIPT">
   function msieversion()
   {
      var ua = window.navigator.userAgent
      var msie = ua.indexOf ( "MSIE " )

      if ( msie > 0 )      // If Internet Explorer, return version number
         return parseInt (ua.substring (msie+5, ua.indexOf (".", msie )))
      else                 // If another browser, return 0
         return 0

   }
   </SCRIPT>
```

As a note, css is for **styling** your sheet, and so you would need to add this css via javascript or other scripting language.

---

It is a little excessive for what you need, but stripping it down (so as to not get the version number). It forms quite a good basis for your test.

---

## A Good Example

---

> The following example demonstrates how to detect the browser version from a client-side script. 
>      Note that this example does not specifically check for platform version, such as Windows 95, Windows >NT, Windows 3.1, and so forth, which require a separate userAgent substring check when applicable:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">
   if ( msieversion() >= 4 )

      document.write ( "This is Internet Explorer 4 or later" );

   else if ( msieversion() >= 3 )

      document.write ( "This is Internet Explorer 3" );

   else

      document.write ( "This is another browser" );

   </SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <style>
        #element{top: 20px;}
    </style>
<![end if]-->
```

conditional comments that works for IE.